# AWS API Gateway Routing

Tags: aws-lambda

How can route a request from API Gateway based towards the lambda functions A/B/C based in the fact that **specific header** is present or not?

```
https://api.example.com/prod

if the headers "UserType" is:

guest -> redirect to lambda A
normal -> redirect to lambda B
admin -> redirect to lambda C
```

I know how only using different URL, e.g:

```
https://api.example.com/prod
https://api.example.com/dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not possible. We can bind only one Lambda function with a specific resource of API Gateway. The headers are accessible as an event parameter within the lambda function itself.

Preferred way would be to create 3 different functions(your business logic's will reside here) within your lambda & based on usertype you can call the function.

And if you really want to make use of three different lambdas, you can make use of **invoke** method available in aws-sdk. You can refer following link for code syntax & example.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

2nd method will definitely increase the response time.

Comment: Very clear answer! thanks for taking the time and help a total stranger.